# Generic foreach loop for different property

Tags: c#, generics, foreach, generic-collections, generic-method

I am trying to use a generic method for foreach loop which would pass different parameter as the argument.

In this example below I would like to pass different parameters(EmployeeDisplayOrder or EmployeeEnrollOrder)

```
public void SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder(ICollection<Employee> employees)
{
   //some code

   foreach( var emp in employees)
   {
      UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(employee.id, e => e.EmployeeDisplayOrder);
   }
}

public void SaveEmployeeEnrollOrder(ICollection<Employee> employees)
{
   //some code

   foreach( var emp in employees)
   {
     UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(employee.id, e => e.EmployeeEnrollOrder);
   }
}
```

I would like to have something like this

```
public void UpdateEmployeeOrders(ICollection<Employee> employee)
{ 
  foreach( var emp in employees)
  {
    UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(employee.id, //generic property);
  }
}
```

and call this UpdateEmployeeOrders generic method from SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder and SaveEmployeeEnrollOrder.

Method signature for UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder

```
UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder( int employeeid, params Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] property)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the type of the 2nd parameter of `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder`? `string`, `int`, something else?

Comment: It does not appear to be a `int`, it appears to be some kind of delagate, something with the form `Func<Something, int>`.

Comment: Lets assume this is Employee class.                                   Public class Employee { public int id; public int EmployeeDisplayOrder; public int EmployeeEnrollOrder; }

Comment: I don't care what employee looks like, I wanted to know what the `????` was in the method signature `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(int id, ???? parameter)` that you have in the first two examples. Is it `Func<Employee, int>`, `Func<Employee, T>`, `Expression<Func<Employee, T>>`, or what?

Comment: Just provide the entire signature of `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder`, so that we don't need to make any assumptions about it at all.

Comment: Func<Employee, object>

Comment: UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder( int employeeid, params Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] property)

Comment: @Ell - code doesn't work in comments. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your answer... you're using lambdas... so pass a delegate in your method.

```
public void SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder<T>(ICollection<Employee> employees, Func<Employee, T> fetchProperty)
{
   //some code

   foreach( var employee in employees)
   {
      UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(employee.id, fetchProperty(employee));
   }
}
```

Then you would call it similar to what you had:

```
SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder(employees, e => e.EmployeeDisplayOrder);
```

or

```
SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder(employees, e => e.EmployeeEnrollOrder);
```

Comment: Here it is not possible to pass e => e.EmployeeDisplayOrder as below           SaveEmployeeDisplayOrder(employees, e => e.EmployeeDisplayOrder);          because EmployeeDisplayOrder is a property of employee and employee is a collection.

Comment: but `e` is a single `employee` from the collection `employees`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I had to make sure the method signature for UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder was same.

Answer (score 10):

Have the method accept an expression, just as the method you're passing it to does:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void UpdateEmployeeOrders(IEnumerable<Employee> employees,
         Expression<Func<Employee, object>> selector)
    {
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder(employee.id, selector);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, since the only thing we ever do with `employees` is iterate over it, we can type the parameter as `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection`.  It provides all of the guarantees that this methods needs, while allowing a broader range of possible input types.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Currently we have no idea what `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder` looks like.  I made the assumption that it itself is generic, so this would work as-is.  If it requires a specific type for its selector, then the same constraint would need to be added here, yes.

Comment: Since you are passing the selector which takes an `Employee` and passing it to a function with only the `id` property, how will `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder` have an `employee` to use the selector with?  Don't you need to pass the employee instead of just the id?

Comment: @Harrison how did `UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder` do it in the first two code examples the OP provided?

Comment: @Harrison Who knows.  It's what the code in the OP appears to be using though, I simply matched that.

Comment: Thank you all. It worked. I had to make sure the method signature for UpdateSpecificEmployeeOrder was same.